# Imported library in UI5 app disappear when calling it

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have downloaded [this library](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js) into my project and put it into "lib" folder in my project.
[image: project folder tree]

Then I add it into the cotroller of my view, when I want to call it when clicking the button, as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC)

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "Test_ScreenRecordingTest_ScreenRecording/lib/RecordRTC"
], function(Controller, RecordRTC) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("Test_ScreenRecordingTest_ScreenRecording.controller.View1", {
    onStartRecording: function(){
        debugger;

        var mediaConstraints = { video: true, audio: true };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(this.successCallback.bind(this)).catch(this.errorCallback);
    },

    successCallback: function(stream) {
        // RecordRTC usage goes here
        var options = {
          mimeType: 'video/webm', // or video/webm\;codecs=h264 or video/webm\;codecs=vp9
          audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
          videoBitsPerSecond: 128000,
          bitsPerSecond: 128000 // if this line is provided, skip above two
        };
        //jQuery.sap.require("Test_ScreenRecordingTest_ScreenRecording.lib.RecordRTC");
        this.recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, options);
        this.recordRTC.startRecording();
    },

    errorCallback: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
        debugger;
    },

    onStopRecording: function(){
        this.recordRTC.stopRecording(function (audioVideoWebMURL) {
            video.src = audioVideoWebMURL;

            var recordedBlob = this.recordRTC.getBlob();
            debugger;
            this.recordRTC.getDataURL(function(dataURL) {
                debugger;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

If I don't use the RecordRTC variable, I can see it in the debugger. If I use it, it appears as "undefined". So can never call it.

Could you please help??Ç

**EDIT 09-feb-2018:** Solved declaring a new variable in the Controller extension

```
return Controller.extend("Test_ScreenRecordingTest_ScreenRecording.controller.View1", {

    //this line solved the issue
    RecordRTC: RecordRTC,

    onStartRecording: function(){
        debugger;

        var mediaConstraints = { video: true, audio: true };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(this.successCallback.bind(this)).catch(this.errorCallback);
    },
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The dependency string in your code looks strange:
"Test_ScreenRecording**Test_ScreenRecording**/lib/RecordRTC".

Can it be a typo?

Anyway, the dependency path should be like this: "*<app ID from manifest.json>*/lib/RecordRTC".

Comment: Thank you slkorolev. The path is correct, it is duplicated because when you create a new app from template and use same "app name" and "namespace" in the initial wizard it appears like that. However the File is imported. I can see it in the RecordRTC variable when stopping in the debugger statement into "onStartRecording" event handler. But if I try to use it, like in the "successCallback", or adding a new assignment (i.e. this.record = RecordRTC) into "onStartRecording", then the variable appears as "undefined"